# jQuery carousel that zooms in/out on feature item

Tags: jquery, plugins, slider, slideshow, carousel

I'm looking for a jQuery plugin which is like a product carousel, the carousel has a few items on it, and one key item is centered which is view at 100%, while the rest of the products on the side are maybe 80% and small as it goes down the back. You can pan through the products using navigation arrows or by clicking on them to bring them to the front.

Imagery to better describe what I'm after - https://minus.com/mroR6PY1U

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/freebies/jquery-carousel-plugins-tutorials/ Checkout the first one